# How to display image from another page in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to start a greasemonkey plugin to an existing page. The plugin should fetch and display some images automatically, each image from different pages.

I thought of using **`jQuery.get("link", function(data))`** and hide the page and display the images only but on an average to display 4 images I should load 6 webpages into present webpage it is creating a delay in loading.

Is there any other work around to create a function that loads the page html of all image pages in background or in another tab and get the **`href`** of **`<a>`** tag's in that page, into my page and load only images into my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this solution below.**
Just put the URLs you want in the "pages" array. When the script runs, it makes Ajax calls in the background. When they are ready, it searches the source returned for images and picks one randomly. If found, it wraps the image in a link to the page where it found it (or if available, the image's url) and inserts the linked image to the top of the body of your own current page.

**You can try the code by pasting it into your browser's JavaScript console** and it will add the images to the current page.

**You also see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lcj3918/3/**

```
//pages you want
var pages =
[
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random'
]

//a simple function used to make an ajax call and run a callback with the target page source as an argument when successful
function getSubPageSource(url, successCallback)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            //when source returned, run callback with the response text
            successCallback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    //requires a proxy url for CORS
    var proxyURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

    xhr.open('GET', proxyURL+url, true);

    //set headers required by proxy
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/");
    xhr.send();
}

//a function that extract images from given url and inserts into current page
function injectImagesFrom(url)
{
    getSubPageSource(url, function(data)
    {
        //trim source code to body only
        var bodySource = data.substr(data.indexOf('<body ')); //find body tag
        bodySource = bodySource.substr(bodySource.indexOf('>') + 1); //finish removing body open tag
        bodySource = bodySource.substring(0, bodySource.indexOf('</body')); //remove body close tag

        //create an element to insert external source
        var workingNode = document.createElement("span");
        //insert source
        workingNode.innerHTML = bodySource;

        //find all images
        var allImages = workingNode.getElementsByTagName('img');

        //any images?
        if (allImages.length > 0)
        {
            //grab random image
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allImages.length);
            var randomImage = allImages.item(randomIndex);
            //add border
            randomImage.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid red;');
            //restrain size
            randomImage.setAttribute('width', 200);
            randomImage.setAttribute('height', 200);

            //check if parent node is a link
            var parentNode = randomImage.parentNode;
            if (parentNode.tagName == 'A')
            {
                //yes, use it
                var imageURL = parentNode.getAttribute('href');
            }
            else
            {
                //no, use image's page's url
                var imageURL = url;
            }

            //add a link pointing to where image was taken from
            var aLink = document.createElement("a");
            aLink.setAttribute('href', imageURL);
            aLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

            //insert image into link
            aLink.appendChild(randomImage);

            /* INSERT INTO PAGE */

            //insert image in beginning of body
            document.body.insertBefore(aLink,document.body.childNodes[0]);

            //remove working node children
            while (workingNode.firstChild) {
                workingNode.removeChild(workingNode.firstChild);
            }
            //unreference
            workingNode = null;
        }
    });
}

for (var ii = 0, nn = pages.length; ii < nn; ii++)
{
    injectImagesFrom(pages[ii]);
}
```

Comment: I edited the code to get the link the image is wrapped in too, if available.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply, seems you understood my problem correctly. But my page is "https" so it is giving some cross origin issues with your code but as I mention in my question "get function" is working fine for me, can you make any edit in your so it could be use full or me.

Comment: OK, done! I found another CORS proxy that allows SSL. I've edited the code above and also changed the jsfiddle link to the new demo. 

Please kindly up vote and accept my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate your assistance for me, it is still giving some error as below.         "Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with"- syntax error.  And also says cross-origin may be because of above syntax error(Sorry but don't take me bad I don't have enough reputation to vote for you I'm new here).

Comment: Is your browser up to date?

Comment: No problem about the up vote then. Simply clicking the checkmark to accept as best answer for now would be good enough. Try it in a different browser. I'll check back with you when I get home later. Good luck in the meantime.

Comment: Ok. Try this. I've added some headers. Does it at least work in the jsfiddle example?